# A new CAPTCHA using sentences?

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha, spam-prevention

I was just thinking about how [recaptcha is getting harder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496545/are-recaptcha-captchas-getting-harder-or-is-just-me) when I thought about another posible solution. Images won't last forever so we will need something else some day - like human logic or emotion. Google and others are trying grouping images by category (find the image that doesn't belong) but that requires a large amount of images and doesn't work for the blind.

Anyway, what if a massive collection of text was gathered (public-domain books from each language) and a sentence was shown to the user with 1 (or 2) words that were a select box of choices? Only computers that knew correct English/Spanish/German grammar would be able to tell which of the words belonged in the sentence.

Would there be any problems with this approach? I would assume that it would be easy enough for anyone that knew the language that the sentense was displayed in to figure out the answer easier than trying to read the reCAPTCHA text. Plus, storing an insane number of sentences would only take a couple gigabytes of space and wouldn't take anywhere near the CPU time creating images/audio takes. In other words, anyone could host their own captcha system with minimal impact on system performance.

**Is there a problem with this approach?** More specifically I'm looking for the main problem with this approach.

Comment: I voted to close accidentally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem with this is language dependency.

The fact that you can understand a language and read for example an English site does not mean you are able to produce semantically correct sentences. So for most people, it could turn out to be an annoyance.

Comment: Well, site owners do not need to produce the sentences. That is why I said use public domain books (which have already been proof-read). The sentences will be correct and the user just simply has to choose the language they want the sentence to come from.

Comment: Sorry, I read it incorrectly. Your right, perhaps certain words could be shown as obvious (like nouns instead of verbs) Anyway, the user must speak some language correctly - so just show a sentence in that language.

Answer (score 1):

How many options do you want to present to the user? If you want to cut out 90% of spam then you must present 10 options, which is a little unwieldy (giving users and bots a 10% chance of even guessing). Fewer options, less spam caught. And you can never eliminate it all. That's probably the main problem I could think of.

Comment: Good point. There would need to be a decent sized choice, that is why I mention 2 words since a single word with 10 choices doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say Google's n-gram would be able to pick out the correct word with ease.

Comment: I wasn't aware of Googles n-gram. Looks like I found a new data mining jackpot!