# How to reduce recaptcha difficulty level

Tags: php, recaptcha

Some of the captchas produced by reCAPTCHA are unreadable.
Are there any configurations that we could use in order to lower difficulty level of reCAPTCHA (I'm using reCAPTCHA PHP API)

**OR** Are there any reCAPTCHA like services that doesn't use php gd library?

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of a captcha?

Comment: Make it easier and hackers/spammers might p0wn your captcha like [I did last week :)](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15956018#15956018)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reduce the Recaptcha difficulty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725461/how-to-reduce-the-recaptcha-difficulty)

Comment: @TheBlueDog: reCAPTCHA captchas are almost unreadable sometimes. That  kind of difficulty would reduce the usability of my web page.
See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496545/are-recaptcha-captchas-getting-harder-or-is-just-me

Comment: @j08691 : I saw that, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google's Recaptcha has a Security Preference slider.

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me while developing using localhost as domain. Any ideas? I have it set to "Easiest for users".

Comment: I would turn off Recaptcha for localhost using code (such as configuration / feature toggle) but leave it enabled in your UAT / staging environment.